# Pronunciation of some letters

Tags: произношение

- Even though the letter **щ** is many times transliterated as **shch** or **shtch** (depending on the transliteration language), is it actually pronounced as **[шч]**, or rather, as an extended **[ш]**, or as a double **[шш]**?
- Is letter **х** equivalent of English **h**, of French **r** (like in ***r***éponse), or something in-between?
- Is **ы** a fusion of the almost deaf **"e"** in French (*crêp**e***, *joli**e***) and a short **[й]** sound?
- Does letter **ъ** extend the preceding consonant?
- Does letter **ь** shorten the preceding consonant?

Comment: for the record **щ** is pronounced as **[шч]** in proper Ukrainian

Comment: please, tend to ask one question per task.

Answer (score 5):

- "Щ" is neither [шч], nor extended [ш] nor double [ш]. It's a soft "ш", similar to "ch" in "Chicago" and to "x" in Portuguese "xicara".
- "х" is similar to English "h" in "house", "home", "hay" etc.
- "ы" is a hard case :) Say "ee" (as in "beef") and then try to move your tongue backwards. That sound would be quite close to "ы". Another method: start saying "oo" (as in "book") and the move your lips like you wants to say "ee".
- no, unlike some languages there's no long and short consonants and vowels in Russian.
- no.

Comment: Although a vulgar example, but if you say "shit" with enough frustration (and stretching the "sh"), it will sound almost exactly like the "щ". I am not aware of any other English word with this property.

Comment: щ-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1dnqKGuezo&list=PL6js2X8b1MrjPXZBLkcTutcr3gic7N9-h&index=96&ab_channel=SugeKnight187

Answer (score 5):

- **Щ:** `[шч]` is a relic. It lingers in transliteration and some textbooks, but that pronunciation went pretty much extinct towards the end of the 20th century. Modern **щ** is an extended, palatalised (soft, "sharp") `[ш’:]`. Meaning it's closer to the English `sh` than basic `[ш]` — in fact, it "overshoots" the English sound and ends up even further in the back, and even sharper-sounding.
- **Х:** Spanish `j` as in **Juana**. German `ch` as in **machen** (*not* as in **Milch**). Scottish **loch** if pronounced authentically. More intense than English `h`, and completely unvoiced. Nothing like the French uvular `r`.
- **Ы:** a single vowel. Transliteration conventions tend to obscure the fact that it's fairly close to the English `[i]`, especially American English and especially after non-plosives, as in **sift** or **lid**. Still, it's pronounced noticeably further in the back of the mouth. Turkish undotted `ı` (**balık**) is more or less the same sound.
- **Ъ, Ь:** I have to disagree with Abakan, Russian doubled consonants are technically "long", but that's not what these letters do. Word-finally, **ь** palatalises/"softens" the preceding consonant (hence the name "soft sign"); mid-word, both are basically pronounced `[j]`. The difference is supposed to be that the consonant before **ъ** isn't supposed to palatalise (hence the name "hard sign"), but a lot of the time, most speakers including myself palatalise it anyway.

Comment: So is it always best to palatalise the letter before the "ъ"--подъем итп?

Comment: @VCH250 Not really, since not palatalising is still the norm. Actually I'm less and less sure of that last bit I said. I may have overgeneralised from words starting with `объ-`. **Подъем** certainly sounds more natural with a "hard" `д`. Come to think of it, in **дьявол**, it's sometimes unpalatalised *despite* the soft sign. My overall point was, it's not a terribly big deal to mix them up.

Comment: I'm guessing that happens in fast speech? Or, out of curiosity, when do you change them up :)

Answer (score 2):

**Щ** is also quite close to an Italian consonant, as in *prosciutto*. But a bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

The closest English sound to Щ would be, indeed, [ch] in  Chicago. The difference is that [ch] is pronounced by unblocking passage of air that was blocked by tongue and [щ] is a continous sound, similar to [sh] . \

Pronouncion of many words containing Щ can be found online, see, for example Щука on Forvo.com

link: https://forvo.com/word/%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0/